# massive string array (40000) elements in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listbox

I know this is a stupid question, I need to let you guys know that I am fully aware that it is useless in 99% of situations to make a listbox with this many elements in c#:

That being said I need this to be done...is there any way to populate a listbox with 40000 elements without it completely destroying performance/freezing up, thanks!

note: I have tried it, this is per the exact requirements of a professor...when adding 40000 elements through a DataSource and DataBind the application freezes up

Comment: yes see the above note thanks

Answer (score 1):

You tell me.

```
for(i=0;i<40000;i++)
{
listBox1.Items.Add("click me");   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if is possible (I never tried it), the usability for this form will be 0.

In that cases a more usable implementation is via lookup text-boxes and lists, where the user can enter a text to search record that matches this text and displays them in a any kind of list.

Answer (score 1):

It is of course possible to do it, but not very practicable.

When using a desktop technology like WinForms or WPF, for a large number of items like this you are better off using something like an auto complete textbox, and have it set to filter/search after the user has typed two or three characters. In this case you can also use a control that offers scrolling virtualisation - this means that there is only a limited number of UI elements created in the scrolling portion of the dropdown, and those elements get reused when a scroll occurs. If you don't use virtualisation then a new element gets created for every list item that gets scrolled in to view. (Note that Silverlight controls have this functionality - just in case it's an option).

For ASP.NET though I would suggest that you do not want to do anything that would cause a large transfer of data (large items, or small items but lots of them) as it won't be performant. Instead you should look to do what Google does - retrieve search results in a paged fashion.